# Pjsip sends second INVITE after receiving OK

Tags: sip, pjsip

I'm using Java wrapper for pjsip. I noticed strange behavior, consider following flow ->

1. PJSIP sends first invite which looks completely fine. First INVITE does not contain TO tag as expected.

   To: sip:11643139125@81.243.146.151;
2. Server sends back Trying, Ringing, Session In Progress, and finally compltely valid OK messag, which contains TO tag.
3. OK message sent by server has not been acked by client. Instead PJSIP sends seconds INVITE wich contains TO tag sent by server

   To: sip:11643139125@81.243.146.151;tag=4NLnv0RNr8qvK2MY

I suspect that INVITE request should not contain TO tag. In responce Asterisk answers with SIP/2.0 491 Request Pending.

Why PJSIP sends second INVITE, why seconds INVITE contains TO tag ?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like re-INVITE, perhaps related to lock_codec account configuration option (2nd party did not reply with single codec answer) - you can try disabling it for test purposes. Would you get same result with original user agent (pjsua)?